# Firebase reading List returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an application to share fuel stops with the rest of my family.
However, I am new to firebase. In this example I created the Class Eintrag (Entry)

```
public class Eintrag {
    String name;
    double kilometerstand;
    double liter;
    double preis;
    String datum;

    public Eintrag()
    {}

    public Eintrag(String name, double kilometerstand, double liter, double preis, String datum) {
        this.name = name;
        this.kilometerstand = kilometerstand;
        this.liter = liter;
        this.preis = preis;
        this.datum = datum;

    }

    public static void neuerEintrag(int index, String name, double kilometerstand, double liter, double preis, String datum) {

        MainActivity.log.add(index, new Eintrag(name, kilometerstand, liter, preis, datum));
    }

    public static void neuerEintrag(String name, double kilometerstand, double liter, double preis, String datum) {

        int index = MainActivity.log.size();
        MainActivity.log.add(index, new Eintrag(name, kilometerstand, liter, preis, datum));
    }

    // FIREBASE
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getKilometerstand() {
        return kilometerstand;
    }

    public double getLiter() {
        return liter;
    }

    public double getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public String getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public String setName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double setKilometerstand() {
        return kilometerstand;
    }

    public double setLiter() {
        return liter;
    }

    public double setPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public String setDatum() {
        return datum;
    }
    //FIREBASE
}
```

and try to retrieve the List of Objects I uploaded earlier. Now when I try to pull the List, or use the child method to retrieve a single value, it always returns null. I don't know why, please help.

```
public class Firebase {

    static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    static DatabaseReference lastEntry = database.getReference("LastEntry");
    static DatabaseReference eintrag = database.getReference("Eintrag");

    static int index;
    protected static List<Eintrag> freshLog;
    static int LastEntry;
    static String test;

    public static void lastEntry() {

        lastEntry.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                LastEntry=toIntExact((Long) dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
    }

    public Firebase(){
    }

    protected static void getData(){

        eintrag.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                GenericTypeIndicator<List<Eintrag>> e = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Eintrag>>() {};

                // freshLog= dataSnapshot.getValue(e);

                test= dataSnapshot.child("3").child("datum").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
    }

    public static void setData(){
        Eintrag.neuerEintrag("R", 23000, 4.5, 6.7, "12.08.99");
        Eintrag.neuerEintrag("L", 24000, 3.4, 7.2, "UWE");
        Eintrag.neuerEintrag("C", 25000, 42.8, 2.4, "KAI");
        Eintrag.neuerEintrag("R", 26000, 4, 5.4, "Burkhardt");
        eintrag.setValue(MainActivity.log);
    }
}
```

Here is my Firebase-Structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxs7p.jpg

And here my debugging info:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Re4Q.jpg

PS: I know my code is a mess, I started with the basics of the basic knowledge I remembered from school.

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate what is the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

To read the Eintrag node childs, you should be doing:

```
    database.getReference().child("Eintrag")
```

Also, to make it more general, use ChildEventListener instead of ValueEventListener. This way you can listen to changes in the Eintrag, either it is an element that was added, changed value, removed, moved or canceled. You can implement strategies to deal with one of this changes separately in their on method in the ChildEventListener.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for helping me. Secondly, database.getReference().child("Eintrag") didnt change anything

Comment: ok, lets see... how are you storing the value in Firebase? Manually or using the setData method?

Comment: SetData. I can neither retrieve the list as a whole, nor can I retrieve single objects, nor can I retrieve single values. I can however store single variables and read them, so I am currently working on an adapter to convert the Entrys in a bunch of strings I upload piece by piece with setValue. Just lost the patience for storing the objects, been trying that for 3 days. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: I was asking because the way you are storing them its a bit different im used to, so wanna to make sure. I use to store objects like this (adapted to your case): eintrag.push().setValue(new Eintrag("R", 23000, 4.5, 6.7, "12.08.99"));

Comment: no i wasnt using push, i used setData(); and MainActivity.log is a List of objects of Eintrag

Comment: Did you tried getting values using: Eintrag eintrag = dataSnapshot.getValue(Eintrag.class); ?

Comment: Yes. I finished the adapter and it didnt work either, and i have now come to the solution that I had to put the code I needed the Eintrag for in the Listener, because of the asynchronous Listener. Now it works, would probably work with objects aswell. Strange is that the debug information shouldnt have been null all the time, but the debugger was probably quicker than the method again.